# Moving around inside a larger-than-screen image

Tags: processing

Context: Processing v3; Windows 10

I have an 853x2048 pixel image that I want to display fullsize on the screen. A large part of it will disappear off the bottom. I want to use Processing to navigate around inside the image, motion-path like, pause at certain points and also zoom in and out.

The code below is adapted from a demo of the Robot class as I thought that would be the go for moving around inside the image.

This code works but I can't as yet figure out how to move the viewport. And then there's the issue of zooming (which I am yet to address.)

How does one move the mouse so that the image moves or how does one move the image with respect to the viewport?

```java
//
//  how to use java.awt.Robot class in processing ...
//
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

Robot robot;
PFont pfont;
Point save_p;
PImage img;

void setup() {
  try { 
    robot = new Robot();
    robot.setAutoDelay(0);
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  surface.setResizable(true);
  fullScreen();
  img = loadImage("bigpic.jpg");
  pfont = createFont("Impact", 32);
}

void draw() {
  background(#ffffff);
  fill(#000000);

  imageMode(CORNERS);
  image(img, 0, 0, 640*3, 480*8);

  Point p = getGlobalMouseLocation();

  textFont(pfont);
  text("now x=" + (int)p.getX() + ", y=" + (int)p.getY(), 10, 32);

  if (save_p != null) {
    text("save x=" + (int)save_p.getX() + ", y=" + (int)save_p.getY(), 10, 64);
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  switch(key) {
  case 's':
    save_p = getGlobalMouseLocation();
    break;
  case 'm':
    if (save_p != null) {
      mouseMove((int)save_p.getX(), (int)save_p.getY());
    }
    break;
  case 'c':
    break;
  case 't':
    translate(2000, 0);
    break;
  case ' ':
    if (save_p != null) {
      mouseMoveAndClick((int)save_p.getX(), (int)save_p.getY());
    }
    break;
  }
}

Point getGlobalMouseLocation() {
  // java.awt.MouseInfo
  PointerInfo pointerInfo = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
  Point p = pointerInfo.getLocation();
  return p;
}

void mouseMove(int x, int y) {
  robot.mouseMove(x, y);
}

void mouseMoveAndClick(int x, int y) {
  robot.mouseMove(x, y);
  robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
  robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
  robot.waitForIdle();
}
```

Comment: @KevinWorkman, We ended following a completely different path in the end. We wanted to be able to call up a webpage and then use keys to navigate to predefined locations, zoom in and out etc, as a presentation technique. We first of all thought of using PhantomJS to take a fullsize screen shot and then have Processing navigate. We ended up with javascript in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by what you're doing with the `Robot` class.

But in any case, basically what you want to do is draw the image so its Y value is lower, which will cause the image to rise so you can see more of it. Here's a small example:

```
PImage img;
float imageY = 0;

void setup() {
  img = loadImage("bigpic.jpg");
}

void draw() {
  image(img, 0, imageY);
  imageY--;
}
```

You can do something similar with resizing, just by passing in more parameters to the `image()` function.

But it sounds like what you're really looking for are the transformation functions. See the **transform** section of [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/) for more info, but basically you would call the `translate()` function to move the origin. You could also call the `scale()` function to "zoom" in and out.

Here's a little example that moves around a rectangle instead of an image:

```
void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){
  background(64);
  translate(-mouseX, -mouseY);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Don't forget that Processing comes with a ton of examples. In the Processing editor, go to `File > Examples`.